# Deploy to elastic beanstalk config

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

This is my config :

I only have 2 configs in .ebextensions : 01run.config and 02do.config

.ebextensions/01run.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    libxslt: []
    libxslt-devel: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    python-devel: []
    python27-devel: []
```

When deploy to EB , There is error ,
Please help me!! What else should I install ?? Thank you

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
```

django project settings.py :

```
if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code that use/call pg_config ?  Are there others Elastic Beanstalk script that are executed ?  Can you SSH to the machine and see if and where pg_config is installed ?

Comment: do you means settings.py ?

Comment: No I wonder what calls pg_config.  I guess this is Django but I am not sure.  The process that calls pg_config can not find it.  Either it is not installed, either it is not in the PATH of the user running the process that calls it.  Understanding what is calling pg_config will help to solve the problem.  Remember, the error is 'Error: pg_config executable not found.'

Comment: Did you follow these instructions to setup Django on EB ?  It is a been outdated now that EB CLI 3.x is here but easy to adapt to the new CLI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

Comment: the document url you supply is 2.X ???  ````I use sudo pip install awsebcli```` I think I'm EB CLI 3.x . But I'm still stuck with this.